# finite rank projection

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

In Murphy's book,there is a statement:If p is a finite rank projection on $H$,then $pB(H)p$ is finite dimensional.

My question:Given  any $S\subset B(H)$,$S$ does not contain $Id_H$.Does there exist a projection $p$ such that the dimension of $pSp$ is finite but not zero?

Comment: Do you mean $S \subset B(H)$?

Comment: yes，a typo .I have reedited it.

Comment: Since you talk about dimension of $pSp$, I guess you want $S$ to be of a certain type, e.g. a subspace or subalgebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question can be reduced to whether given nonzero $T\in B(H)$, there exists a finite-rank projection $P$ such that $PTP\ne0$.

There is a direct construction of such $P$, but one easy way to see that it has to exist is to take an increasing net of finite-rank projections $\{p_j\}$ such that $p_j\nearrow I$ wot. Then, as wot is multiplicative on bounded nets, 
$$
p_jTp_j\to T\ \text{ wot}.
$$
So if $pTp=0$ for all finite-rank projections, then $T=0$.

Comment: @mathrookie Assuming $T\neq 0$, take some non-zero vector $x$ such that $y=Tx$ is non-zero.  Let $p$ be the projection onto $\operatorname{span}\{x,y\}$.  Then $pTpx=pTx=py=y$, so $pTp\neq0$.

Comment: @Aweygan,but $p$ may not be a finite rank projection.

Comment: @mathrookie $p$ is a projection onto the span of two vectors, so the rank of $p$ is at most $2\ldots$

Comment: @mathrookie: it doesn't matter; by definition of dimension, a projection onto a 2-dimensional subspace is finite-rank.

Comment: @Martin Argerami,so if we take above finite rank projection $p$,$pSp$ is finite dimensional and nonzero?

Comment: Yes. $\ \ \ \ \ $